# How to make content fill space inside <div> tag in html?

Tags: html, css

I have div that has exact width (280px) and inside it there are 2 hyperlinks and one input text box. The hyperlinks take just a little space. I want the input text box to fill the remaing space in the `div`. How can I do that ?

Html:

```
<div class="notificationArea">
    <a>A</a> <a>B</a>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notificationArea
{
width: 280px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:left;
}
```

Note: I can replace the outer `div` by something else (for example `span`) but I'm trying to avoid tables.

---

EDIT: All elements (both hyperlinks and input) should be on the same line.

---

**EDIT 2:** I want the same think to work when I replace both hyperlinks with images. That is I want a `div` of fixed width that contains 2 images (fixed size) and `input` textboxt that will fill the remainig space.

Http:

```
<div class="notificationArea">
    <img src="someImage" />
    <img src="someImage2" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notificationArea
{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 330px;
}
.notificationArea input
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I got is:
[image: not wanted example]

---

But what I **want** is:
[image: wanted example]

So I don't want the input box to wrap. The solution on the picture uses tables that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said:

> I'm trying to avoid tables.

But, they make this really easy, so here's a `display: table` based answer:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/atckf/)

I can't think of a more eloquent way to do this without resorting to JavaScript.

**CSS:**

```
.notificationArea
{
    width: 280px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:left;
    background: #ccc;
    display: table
}
.notificationArea a, .notificationArea input {
    display: table-cell
}
.notificationArea input {
    width: 100%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="notificationArea">
    <a href="#">A</a> <a href="#">B</a>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: +1 this is the only answer working till now... If nobody figures out something better I guess tables are better then nothing... While they are in CSS I can live with that.

Comment: Yeah, I have no problem with this kind of `table`. It's not changing anything to do with semantics or cluttering your HTML with over 9000 nested tags or any of the usual downsides to `<table>` :)

Comment: Using `display: table` (or `table-cell`) instead of real HTML `table`s caused some trouble for me in the past, especially in different browsers. But if that is enough for you, then it's OK.

Comment: @battal: You're right. It doesn't work with IE7(!), and really old WebKit browsers will require a wrapper element with `display: table-row`.

Comment: So how is that ? It will not work with some IE ? Or it just causes problems in special cases ?

Comment: Strange: in live demo it work but when I copy the same code to VisualStudio editor then the live view displays input text box wrapped to the nex line... Anyone knows why ? Is it going to work when I run it ?

Comment: @thirtydot So the point is this only really works for IE. When I there are images (`img`) instead of hyperlinks (`a`) then it wraps the input text box anyway...

Comment: @drasto: You didn't say anything about images before :) Can you edit this to show how you're adding the images and show me how it breaks? http://jsfiddle.net/atckf/ - the point *isn't* that it "only works in IE". It will work in almost every browser except IE7.

Comment: @thirtydot I don't understand how you web developers can create all those sites... I would expect the solution that works with hyperlinks to work with any other element (for instance with images)... But when I use images the solution does not work with lates Firefox, Chrome and Safary. It stil works with IE 8. I'll edit my question in few minutes

Comment: @thirtydot I've addited my question to show my problems with images. Thank you for any advice that you may provide.

Comment: @drasto: Or this if you really don't want `<a>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/atckf/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can give `a`'s a specific width and remaining to the `input`:

CSS:

```
.notificationArea
{
    width: 280px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:left;
}
.notificationArea a {display: inline-block; width: 10%;}
.notificationArea input {display: inline-block; width: 75%;}/* 5% for white space */
```

You can take or give a few points to percentages.

Comment: Well but I need this to be adaptive to the changes of length of those hyperlinks. Their lenght may be variable (they are generated).

Comment: Then your best luck seems to use HTML tables (which is not the plague), unless you use some Javascript to set widths dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

use a nowrap (white-space: nowrap ) on the div and force the textbox to be width=100%?

```
  .notificationArea
  {
    width: 280px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
  input
  {
    width:100%;
  }
```

Comment: Seems that this is not working - the textbox is wrapped to the next line and (strange!) it is longer then the `div` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could put relatives values to the input for example width:100% and fix the height.

Comment: Does not work either. Input gets wrapped to next line and it is longer then 280px (strange) that is longer then the `div` itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question and the simplest way to make this work on modern browsers is to set the **display property to flex.**

For example in the pic below, you can extend the div to full height of the other contents using the display property.

```
display:flex;
```

[image]